# Is it safe to use Celery with django-kombu in production?

Tags: celery, django-celery

Is it safe to use Celery with django-kombu in production? I have this setup on Heroku, so my app's database (postgres) is the message transport. I'm seeing intermittent problems e.g. a task is completed BUT I still see its status as pending. I'm wondering if this is because of contention issues. I've seen some people recommend that django-kombu not be used in production: https://gondor.io/support/celery/

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend it.

Celery is polling the job queue for messages, so if the queue is the db I think it is not a good idea to hit it periodically